# texmaker does not generate a pdf file

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmaker

Have no idea why but I cannot compile my tex file

the last part of the log file are

```
    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/EvenCycleCross-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF
     inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
    <figs/EvenCycleCross-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=174, 83.31125pt x 88.33pt>
    File: figs/EvenCycleCross-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
    <use figs/EvenCycleCross-eps-converted-to.pdf>
    Package pdftex.def Info: figs/EvenCycleCross-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on inpu
    t line 553.
    (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 66.64908pt x 70.66408pt.
    
    Package natbib Warning: Citation `BermanY2012' on page 7 undefined on input lin
    e 560.
    
    [7 <./figs/PocketGr-eps-converted-to.pdf> <./figs/EvenCycleCross-eps-converted-
    to.pdf>]
    
    Package natbib Warning: Citation `BermanY2012' on page 8 undefined on input lin
    e 569.
    
    
    LaTeX Warning: Reference `tiletomat' on page 8 undefined on input line 569.
    
    
    LaTeX Warning: Reference `tiletomat' on page 8 undefined on input line 597.
    
    
    LaTeX Warning: Reference `tiletomat' on page 8 undefined on input line 597.
    
    Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <figs/CycleToEdge.eps>
    (epstopdf)                    date: 2021-07-07 19:17:38
    (epstopdf)                    size: 58108 bytes
    (epstopdf)             Output file: <figs/CycleToEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf>
    (epstopdf)                    date: 2021-07-08 16:30:51
    (epstopdf)                    size: 10370 bytes
    (epstopdf)             Command: <miktex-epstopdf --outfile=figs/CycleToEdge-eps
    -converted-to.pdf figs/CycleToEdge.eps>
    (epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 601.
    Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
    
    
    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/CycleToEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF in
    clusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
    <figs/CycleToEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=205, 56.21pt x 88.33pt>
    File: figs/CycleToEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
    <use figs/CycleToEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf>
    Package pdftex.def Info: figs/CycleToEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input l
    ine 601.
    (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 44.96805pt x 70.66408pt.
    Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <figs/CycleToInfEdge.eps>
    (epstopdf)                    date: 2021-07-07 19:17:42
    (epstopdf)                    size: 60096 bytes
    (epstopdf)             Output file: <figs/CycleToInfEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf>
    (epstopdf)                    date: 2021-07-08 16:30:53
    (epstopdf)                    size: 10721 bytes
    (epstopdf)             Command: <miktex-epstopdf --outfile=figs/CycleToInfEdge-
    eps-converted-to.pdf figs/CycleToInfEdge.eps>
    (epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 602.
    Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
    
    
    pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./figs/CycleToInfEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF
     inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
    <figs/CycleToInfEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=206, 60.225pt x 99.37125pt>
    File: figs/CycleToInfEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
    <use figs/CycleToInfEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf>
    Package pdftex.def Info: figs/CycleToInfEdge-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on inpu
    t line 602.
    (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 48.18005pt x 79.4971pt.
    Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <figs/tiling.eps>
    (epstopdf)                    date: 2021-07-07 19:19:20
    (epstopdf)                    size: 27223 bytes
    (epstopdf)             Output file: <figs/tiling-eps-converted-to.pdf>
    (epstopdf)                    date: 2021-07-08 16:30:56
    (epstopdf)                    size: 0 bytes
    (epstopdf)             Command: <miktex-epstopdf --outfile=figs/tiling-eps-conv
    erted-to.pdf figs/tiling.eps>
    (epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 603.
    Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
    
   

 Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
    
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./figs/tiling-eps-converted-to.pdf): reading imag
    e file failed
     ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

My file compiles on overleaf but not with texmaker.  Also I don't know why texmaker keeps wanting to search for tiling-eps-converted-to.pdf  when code specifies  tiling.eps.
The whole log file is too long to include.

Comment: TeXmaker is irrelevant. The problem is that  `pdflatex` cannot compile EPS, and try to convert the images to PDF and use the PPF automatically, but for some reason cannot read one (maybe because is a version **1.7**?). Conclusion: Be sure that you have a non-corrupt PDF version of all the images, preferably PDF 1.5, and use only  `\includegraphics{myfile.pdf}` or `\includegraphics{myfile}` (by default will use `myfile.pdf` extension, if exists, otherwise will try to use a `.png` or `.jpg` version).

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to settings Texmaker needs to complete a run.

Do you succeed, when *excluding* the graphics, e.g. when boiling down the document to minimal code, which fails *with* graphic AND passes *without*? (This way you verify "it's running".)

BTW, here's how I configured the QUICK BUILD:

- Lualatex or pdflatex is irrelevant here
- Texmaker has a two step approach: compile + run (pdf) // Quick Build starts both

[image]

As a potential work-around: I successfully can compile to .pdf with .eps graphics; I can confirm they are converted into .pdf. A tool to do the conversion to .eps is e.g. Inkscape, which can also run in batch mode from the command line. https://inkscape.org/

Comment: Just to confirm I should compile with LuaLatex?

Comment: No, my lazyness, you certainly can use the first option as well. What I was trying to say, in my first trials it took me a moment to realize, how TeX/Latex works in this edition. On the command line, as I read, many times you have to repeat compile. Seems to be similar here, and configuring to also View pdf did the trick for me.

Comment: The first option PdfLatex+view pdf fails to produce a pdf

Comment: Hm, can't you get a very simple, basic .tex file being compiled, even with the last option, or any other?? // If so, perhaps installation went wrong (reinstall, as was already proposed), OR configuration still is missing something.

Comment: I got the 3rd option Latex +dvips+ps2pdf+view pdf to work thanks for the help.

Comment: Great. It's always some trial and (t)error ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just re-install Miktex (version up-to-date via admin on your computer). Everything will be OK.